Adobe Illustrator: eye dropper not picking the correct colour
I am exporting a plot to pdf from R (using ggsave() from ggplot2, but probably does not matter), where I set the colour to e.g. #417dcd (blue). I put this pdf in Illustrator, then use Eye Dropper to pick the plot's colour.
No matter what I do, eye dropper does not take the correct colour! I have read a bunch of posts here and tried all the suggested solutions, that is:
– File > CMYK Color or RGB Color
– double click on Eye Dropper tool, change Point Sample to 3x3 Average or 5x5 Average.
As you can see below, nothing works. Only thing that works is manually setting the colour to the HEX code I originally used.
What am I missing? Why is Eye Dropper seeing a different colour?
EDIT: ah, seems like I identified the main source of the issue. I usually have my Illustrator window on a secondary Dell screen. If I move it to my Macbook screen, the colour picked by Eye Dropper is (almost) correct.


I tried playing with the Dell screen settings colour settings (the settings coded into the screen, using the screen's buttons), that does not change it.
Then I tried changing in my Macbook's settings Displays > clicking DELL screen > Colour profile. I tried all possible profiles (quite boring) and found a few that give good (but not perfect) results.
Maybe not a complete or elegant answer, but seems to work.


Calibrate the monitors. Sounds like they aren't calibrated really at all.

Any pointers on how to do that correctly? Thanks

https://www.rtings.com/monitor/learn/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor-settings - and if this is professional use, there are devices, such as X-Rite products, which attach to the monitor and read colors ensuring less human error.
